# Применение математической функции со значениями строк в pandas попарно

Tags: python, pandas

Подскажите как решить такую задачку. Есть таблица с N строк, заполненная числами. Необходимо выполнить попарное сложение элементов в столбцах и деление на их разность. Обычный intersection over union. Примерно то что имеем:

```
     Col1    Col2   Col3
A    
B
C
D
```

Нужно выполнить функцию попарно, чтоб был результат такой:

```
             Col1    Col2   Col3
(A+B)/(A-B)    
(A+C)/(A-C)
(A+D)/(A-D)
(B+C)/(B-C)
(B+D)/(B-D)
```

В колонках соответственно числа которые надо подставить в каждую функцию.

Comment: Приведите пример исходных данных и желаемого результата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так, для поиска пересечений.

```
np_data = list()
for i in range(matr.shape[0] - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, matr.shape[0]):
        np_data.append((i, j, matr[i] & matr[j]))
```